# Laravel Using AJAX to pass Javascript variable to PHP and retrieve those

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can I use Ajax to pass a Javascript variable to Php and retrieving those?

I am using a Jquery Ui Slider and on each slide I want to pass the javascript slider value to php so to say.

I have no ( not much ) experience in Ajax and really appreciate help.

This is how my slider looks:

```
    $("#sliderNumCh").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        step: 1,
        value: numbersOfChapters,
        change : function(e, slider){
            $('#sliderAppendNumCh').empty();
            var i = 0;
            var sliderValue = slider.value;
            var getSliderVal = document.getElementById('sliderValue').value = sliderValue;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: {
                    value: getSliderVal
                },
                success: function (option) {
                    console.log(getSliderVal);
                }
            });
            ...
      }
  })
```

My route example:

**Edit** my route looks like this now:

```
Route::post('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProductPost', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProduct']);
```

**Edits what I have tried:**

```
url: '{{ route("editProductWeb") }}',
```

and got this error:

> ```
> POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/%7BproductID%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ```

and tried this:

```
url: 'edit',
```

and got this error:

> ```
> POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ```

**Edit** my edit controller method:

```
public function editProduct($productRomID = 0)
{
    $product = ProductRom::find($productID);
    $sheets  = Chapters::where('product_id', '=', $productID)->get();

    $productId = $product->id;

    $sheetCount    = count($sheets);

    return view('product.edit', [
        'productId' => $productId,
        'product' => $product,
        'sheets' => $sheets,
        'sheetCount' => $sheetCount,
        'type' => 'edit',
        'route' => 'updateProductRom'
    ]);
}
```

**Edit** using haakym suggestion so far:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "{{ Route('editProduct', $product->id) }}",
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: {
                    value: getSliderVal,
                    productId : getPrId
                },
                success: function (option) {
                    console.log(getSliderVal);
                }
            });
```

does print me the id + the current slider value in my debug, so that works so far. Now I need to get that value and use it in my view(php) any suggestion how to proceed?

using this in my controller method:

```
$sliderValue = $request->input('value');
```

returns me

> null

**Edit** I also tried this:

```
$sliderValue = Input::get('value');
```

which also returned me

> null

**Edit** I added a Log:

```
Log::info(Input::all());
```

This shows the correct slider value and product id on slide.
But my `Input::get('value')` still returns me `null`

**Edit** I think I should add this information:

I changed my routes to this now:

```
Route::get('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProduct']);
Route::post('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProductPost', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProductPost']);
```

The `get` shows the data from the database for a specific product and shows them  in my view, I added the `post` one to post the slidervalue data to the `editProductPost` method and returns afterwards the value(sliderValue) in the edit view, is this correct?(Btw still does not work)

**EDIT**

If I put this in my controller method:

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')){
    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is post method']);
}

return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
```

I keep getting the following error (if I slide):

> POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/54 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

I have this in my head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and put this before my ajax post:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Doing this returns the correct current slider value in the logs:

```
Log::info($request->get('value'));
```

I tried this:

```
    return view('productRom.edit', [
        'value' => $value,
    ]);
```

But I get an error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/73

Comment: It seems good from here. You just have to put the URL of your controller/method into your $.ajax 'url' parameter and then it should work

Comment: ty, so do I have to add `edit` in the `url` I postet the route above in the question

Comment: You can try url: '/edit', if it's not working try the complete URL :)

Comment: /edit is absolute path right? he should just use edit.

Comment: I get this error message `POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @JohnDoe2 Check out [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection)

Comment: I have an csrf_token at the end of my form like this: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Answer (score 1):

As @julqas stated you need to include the URL in your `$.ajax()` method.

As you have a named route `editProduct`, you can output the link using blade:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{{ route("editProduct" }}',
  ...
```

**Edit 1**:

Your route is `get` and your ajax method is `post`, I guess this is the issue. You need to make them the same.

If you change the route to `post` you will need to add the CSRF token to the ajax request when it is sent. There is some guidance on the docs how to do this here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

The docs recommend adding this in your HTML head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then use the following code before sending the request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

alternatively you can add it to the request in the ajax call.

**Edit 2**

A side point - I was just guessing what the error is, it would have been better if I'd asked you if you could debug it yourself in order to see what the error was. Learning to debug ajax requests is very useful and not too difficult.

The best way to do that is by using the developer console in your browser of choice when making the ajax request. If you're using Chrome for example open `Developer tools` and then click on the `Network` tab before making your request. After making the request you can inspect the request and its details. Hope that helps!

**Edit 3**

I would change your `editProduct()` method to not accept any parameter and instead get the `id` value for the product from the request

```
public function editProduct()
{
    // value here is referring to the key "value" in the ajax request
    $product = ProductRom::find(\Request::get('value');
    ...
}
```

Consider changing the `value` key in your json to something more useful, such as productId

```
data: {
    productId: getSliderVal
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error `POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/%7BproductID%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: thank you I changed it (the route to post, added the csrf meta, and added the ajax header before my ajax post) but I get the same error

Comment: @JohnDoe2 check my edits, let me know if they're not clear!

Comment: 1. can you get the full error details using the developer consolve & network tab. 2. It may be because your route definition defines no parameter whereas the error in your comment shows some sort of parameter `edit/%7BproductID%7D` - what does your `edit()` method look like in your controller?

Comment: ok ill debug it like you told to, ill post the edit method in a minute

Comment: I added the method in the controller, thus if I try to put `edit `instead of `{{ Route('editProduct') }}` in the `url` I get no error but I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: in the network tab it shows me this:`edit 200 xhr jquery.min.js:4 5.4 KB 106 ms `

Comment: The reason `{{ route('editProduct') }}` fails is because it is expecting a parameter as defined in your controller, yet your route declaration in `routes.php` doesn't define any parameters. It would need to look like this: `Route::get('edit/{productId}' ...` then you would do this `{{ route('editProduct', 1) }}` where 1 is the id. In this case though do as I advised in my edit and remove the parameter from the method in your controller.

Comment: Try clicking on the entry of the ajax request to inspect it, you should see `Headers`, `Preview`, `Response`, `Cookies`, `Timing` tabs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117613/discussion-between-john-doe-2-and-haakym).

Comment: if you have time could you help me further with this session

Comment: @JohnDoe2 sure thing. Just update your question once you've made some progress or make a new question and @ me.

Comment: I updated my question, in my log::info I get the correct slider value on slide I "just" need to direct back to the view with that variable(value) but that does not work

Comment: I made a new question which is about that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475451/ajax-laravel-return-view-500-error

Answer (score 0):

you haven't entered value for 'url'. Create any route then put it in url:'{any_route_name}' and then check in console weather your value has been posted or not

You have to do some R&D at your level for this .