# Ajax Laravel return view 500 Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am getting each slider value in slide (Jquery Ui Slider) via Ajax to my Controller.

The Slider + Ajax looks like this:

```
    $("#sliderNumCh").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        step: 1,
        value: numbersOfChapters,
        change : function(e, slider){
            $('#sliderAppendNumCh').empty();
            var sliderValue  = slider.value;
            var getSliderVal = document.getElementById('sliderValue').value = sliderValue;
            var getPrId      = document.getElementById('editId').value;

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "{{ Route('editProductPost', $product->id) }}",
                headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                },
                data: {
                    value: getSliderVal,
                    productId : getPrId
                },
                success: function (option) {
                    console.log(getSliderVal);
                }
            });
        },
    });
```

Thus I do have this in my head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::post('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProductPost', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProductPost']);
```

And in my Controller method I call it like this:

```
public function editProductPost(Request $request)
{
    $sliderValue = $request->get('value');
    Log::info($sliderValue);

    return view('productRom.edit', [
        'sliderValue' => $sliderValue
    ]);
}
```

Log::info($sliderValue) tells me that I do get the correct slider value on each slide.

When I try to return back to my edit view I get this error in the console:

> POST http://localhost/myApp/public/product/edit/73 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

How can I solve this?

**Edit**

Since I have this line in my view:

```
<form action="{{ route($route) }}"...>
```

The route variable was not defined so I added this in my return statement.

```
return view('productRom.edit', [
    'sliderValue' => $sliderValue,
    'route' => 'editProductPost'
]);
```

The error is gone but when I try to access the `$sliderValue` variable like this:

```
<p>{{ isset($sliderValue) ? $sliderValue : "nothing" }}</p>
```

it prints me `nothing`

**Edit**

Controller:

```
    public function editProductPost(Request $request)
    {

        return response()->json([
            'sliderValue' => $request->get('value')
        ]);
   }
```

View(ajax):

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{{ Route('editProductPost', $product->id) }}",
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            data: {
                value: getSliderVal,
                productId : getPrId
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // check it has some data
                if (response.length) {
                    // spit it out
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    console.log('nothing returned');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You said "When I try to return back to my edit view I get this error in the console" try clicking on the post request and what do you see under preview?

Comment: @haakym Ok I think I have it ill edit the question quick

Comment: 1. You haven't done what I have said in my first comment. 2. As I said in our chat the other day "... your editProduct method returns a view, if you're using it for ajax don't return a view, return json data" http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31766104#31766104 - hope that's clear.

Comment: hmm ok, so I cannot return a view with ajax. But how do I use that json data further?

Comment: See my answer. I think you need to read up the docs on how an ajax request works then you will understand why you can't return it a view. Think about why you're using a ajax request, it's so you don't need to go away from the current page/i.e. the current view - so why would you pass it back a view. Returning a view is for when you're NOT using ajax. You want to return json so your `$.ajax` success method can do something with it.

Comment: Great. Hope you can get it working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117797/discussion-between-haakym-and-john-doe-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method should look like this:

```
public function editProductPost(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'sliderValue' => $request->get('value')
    ]);
}
```

You shouldn't be returning a view to a ajax request.

Your ajax success method should look like this (for example):

```
// first arg is the data returned by the controller method
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

and it should ouput something like this:

```
{
    'sliderValue': 4
}
```

Comment: Hmm I will edit my answer and let you know how I edited it (still not working)

Answer (score 0):

Your route is named as editProductPost but you are searching for editProduct